# Getting to Guangzhou from Melbourne

Tags: air-travel, australia, china, china-southern-airlines, guangzhou

I am taking a business trip to Guangzhou from Melbourne is a few months.  I have noticed that there are no direct flights (correct me if I am wrong).  Looks like I have to transfer in Hong Kong.  Because HK and Guangzhou are so close, is there a train/ferry that I can take that would be easier to do than getting a connecting flight.

The trip is paid for by my employer, so I am not too worried about cost, more about convenience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is, in fact, a direct flight from Melbourne to Guangzhou with [China Southern Airlines](http://www.flychinasouthern.com/index.php?lang=en). (They have two websites - the global one, which I've linked to, can accept payments from international credit cards while the Chinese one doesn't. Of course, you can book via third parties like Expedia et al too.) This seems to be the easiest option.

If you want to have a stop-over at Hong Kong for some reason, then you can also get to Guangzhou by train. [Hong Kong MTR runs a service from Hunghom railway station to Guangzhou East](http://www.it3.mtr.com.hk/b2c/frmIndex.asp?strLang=Eng). There are tourist bus services too from HKIA, but they aren't any cheaper (and take longer) so there isn't much point taking one.